# Copy a list using Non blank and Blank rows as a head and tail loop

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, textjoin

HI so I have a set of data that I would like to copy. Basically I would like to create an if function. If we search for a blank row in column B and it is blank, loop to the next row, and continue until the first non blank row. If we hit a non blank copy all the cells from all the blank rows in column c.

```
    Sub NotReadys()

 ' NotReadys Macro'
Dim Z As Integer 'Supplier Beginning Row'
Dim X As Integer 'Next Non Blank row'
Dim Q As Integer '# of suppliers'
Dim Y As Integer 'Paste Row'
Y = 6
'For T = 1 To 195


ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-33


Range("B" & Y).Select
Selection.Copy

Range("E" & Y).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Range("F" & Y).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),FALSE,RC[-3]:R[30]C[-3])"
Range("F" & Y).Select
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-30
Range("F" & Y).Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
    Y = Y + 1
    Next T

    End Sub
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcNOZ.jpg

Comment: You will need to show your code you already have, because StackOverflow is not a free code writing service.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to make a list of all the non-blank values in column B. The list is separated by line feeds so that all the values can go into a single cell. Are you trying to create a number of lists from teh groups of values in column B separated by blanks or just one list?

Comment: @Jeeped Some context I have a list of suppliers and multiple POs(Purchase orders) I have the data organized to be one column suppliers and another POs. The goal is to copy the supplier and all corresponding pos in one cell, till the script finds a new supplier. hence a new non blank and it copys all cells above because those POs correspond to that supplier.I want a Non blank list in column B with all the blanks in B creating an action to copy all the cells in the next column. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having difficulty understanding the structure of your data, but using `For Each x In Selection` might help you. I'm assuming that your data at least similar the below, where the supplier names are in column A, and POs are in column B

```
     |   A   |   B   |   C   |   D   |
-----|-------|-------|-------|-------|
  1  |   s1  |  PO1  |       |       |
-----|-------|-------|-------|-------|
  2  |   s2  |  PO2  |       |       |
-----|-------|-------|-------|-------|
  3  |   s3  |       |       |       |
-----|-------|-------|-------|-------|
  4  |   s4  |  PO3  |       |       |
-----|-------|-------|-------|-------|
```

This code will copy any supplier and PO (where PO isn't blank) to columns C and D:

```
outRow = 1  ' Set this to the index of the first row you want to output to

' Run through each cell in Selection, left to right, top to bottom
For Each selCell In Selection
  ' Check for non-blank, but only if we're looking at column 2 (B)
  If selCell.Column = 2 & selCell <> "" then
    ' Store the selected Row and Column
    sRow = selCell.Row
    sCol = selCell.Column

    ' Has the effect of prefixing ActiveSheet to any values that start with "."
    With ActiveSheet
      ' Copy value from cols 1 and 2 (A & B) to col 3 and 4 (C & D)
      .Cells(outRow, 3).Value = .Cells(sRow, sCol - 1).Value
      .Cells(outRow, 4).Value = selCell.Value
    End With

    outRow = outRow +1  ' Moves to next output row
  End If
Next
```

In my example, assuming you selected A1:B4 before running the function, you will get the below output.

```
     |   A   |   B   |   C   |   D   |
-----|-------|-------|-------|-------|
  1  |   s1  |  PO1  |   s1  |  PO1  |
-----|-------|-------|-------|-------|
  2  |   s2  |  PO2  |   s2  |  PO2  |
-----|-------|-------|-------|-------|
  3  |   s3  |       |   s4  |  PO3  |
-----|-------|-------|-------|-------|
  4  |   s4  |  PO3  |       |       |
-----|-------|-------|-------|-------|
```

I'm guessing that you're using the Macro recording option to produce the code you have; this is a great way to learn how VBA works (most of us have done this at some point), but doesn't produce nice code. The built in documentation in Excel is actually really good and is worth looking at when you hit the limitations of the recorder.

Edit: *The more I look at your question, the less sure I am about what you're asking, but hopefully the above at least pushes you in the right direction.*

Comment: I have attached what the data should like like in the question. Please click on the link. Basically the goal is to automate the copy and pasting of POs per supplier. So when the code finds a new supplier is copys all the POs above. Hope that helps.

Comment: So I think what you're doing would be more easily achieved with a PivotTable. Or you could modify what I've written to concatenate the values into your column F. If you can't modify what I've written, then I'd be doing your homework for you and you'd be unable to amend it when things change.